# HLS stream not working on website with Video.js, but working in VLC Media Player

Tags: http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm trying to embed an HLS stream on my website using Video.js, but for some reason, it's not working. Here's the code I'm using:

---

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <video class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    controls 
    data-setup="{}">
        <source src="http://tv.greatstar.me:80/play/live.php?mac=00:1A:79:58:27:AF&stream=946233&extension=m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
      </video>
</body>
</html>`
```

The stream works fine in VLC Media Player, but it doesn't seem to work on my website. It shows the error "The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support."
I've tried adding different options to the data-setup attribute and setting the mime-type of the HLS stream, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know why this HLS stream might not be working on my website with Video.js, but works fine in VLC Media Player? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!